read() on Poco::Zip::ZipInputStream
I try to read a binary file which is part of a zip archive. Therefore I opened the zip archive with Poco::Zip. Then I read the binary file chunkwise
struct Header
{
    uint64_t tag;
    uint32_t payloadLength;
} __attribute__((packed));

std::ifstream inp("my.zip", std::ios::binary);
Poco::Zip::ZipArchive arch(inp);
Poco::Zip::ZipArchive::FileHeaders::const_iterator it = arch.findHeader("file.dat");
if (it != arch.headerEnd()) {
    Poco::Zip::ZipInputStream inStream(inp, it ->second);
    Header hdr;
    inStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&hdr), sizeof(hdr));
    
    char buffer[hdr.payloadLength];
    inStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), sizeof(hdr.payloadLength));
    
    ...
}


I got garbage data when reading from the ZipInputStream.
When I use
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inStream)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

it works, but I want to avoid this solution because it buffers the complete file in one possible large buffer. What is goning wrong here with read()?

"What is going wrong here with read()?" Principally, inStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), sizeof(hdr.payloadLength));
should be inStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), hdr.payloadLength);

The problem is not the usage of buffers.
The problem is, after the first read(), inStream.fail() == true. Than, I do another read() but this will result in garbage and inStream.fail() == false

Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - From Review

@LTyrone Hi, I raised the disputed flag on this. The new user OP posted it in response to my since deleted answer to their own question in order to tell me that my answer was wrong to identify a buffer-size coding error as the main cause
of their code reading garbage. The OP believes the problem must be something else. This response to me should have been a comment, not an answer. The  buffer-size error is in fact the main problem - I had tested my fix - but I gave up on arguing about the obvious and deleted my answer.
